# Apache - Phantom long requests returning 408?

Tags: http, httpd, apache-2.4

I am having intermittent problems with sites that are running on apache - the boxes would spontaneously work themselves into a tizzy taking up all available CPU and memory in the process.  To this end, I decided to give an apache module called **mod_log_slow** a shot to see if I could get to the bottom of things.

This is what mod_log_slow returns on your average request if it takes more than 1 second:

```
VFz-@RFSe6WBtx2tOdv0qgAAAAw [07/Nov/2014:12:23:05 -0500] elapsed: 1.25 cpu: 0.04(usr)/0.01(sys) pid: 8059 ip: 1.2.3.4 host: www.example.com:80 reqinfo: GET /dining?start=20& HTTP/1.1
```

You can see how this log is generated by taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/yokawasa/mod_log_slow/blob/master/mod_log_slow.c#L562), but it should be relatively self-expanitory.

However, I soon discovered that there were some lines in the slow log that stuck out like a sore thumb.

```
1f7b:545d003d:0 [07/Nov/2014:12:24:13 -0500] elapsed: 53.33 cpu: 0.02(usr)/0.00(sys) pid: 8059 ip: 1.2.3.4 host: (null):80 reqinfo: (null)
```

No host?  No request?  No unique id?  Held open for 53 seconds?  I found the exact request in the normal access log as well, but it was equally perplexing:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [07/Nov/2014:12:24:13 -0500] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
```

What in the wide wide world of sports is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These log lines can come if you open a connection to your server on port 80 like
`telnet 1.2.3.4 80` or `nc 1.2.3.4 80`

but do not send anything and just wait it times out.

It can be anything from just badly written scripts to testing for a dos attack (check out slowloris). But it seems from your log lines that this is not the cause for your CPU problem.

Comment: I have done some further investigation and I have found that it's also possible for browsers to open up a connection to the webserver in anticipation of needing a connection soonish.

In any case, you're right, such connections that don't actually contain a valid HTTP request thus don't end up with a valid request in the logfile as well, and are unlikely to be causing high CPU usage.